# Use Kotlin's data class in service-proxy of Vert.x

Tags: kotlin, vert.x, kapt

I'm trying to pass `data class` to the service-proxy of Vert.x like this:

```java
data class Entity(val field: String)

@ProxyGen
@VertxGen
public interface DatabaseService {
  DatabaseService createEntity(Entity entity, Handler<AsyncResult<Void>> resultHandler);
}
```

However, the service-proxy requires a `DataObject` as the parameter type.

Below are what I've tried so far.
First, I rewrite the data class as:

```kotlin
@DataObject
data class Entity(val field: String) {
  constructor(json: JsonObject) : this(
    json.getString("field")
  )

  fun toJson(): JsonObject = JsonObject.mapFrom(this)
}
```

Although this works, the code is redundant, so I tried the kapt with the following generator:

```
  override fun process(annotations: Set<TypeElement>, roundEnv: RoundEnvironment): Boolean {
    roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(ProxyDataObject::class.java).forEach { el ->
      val className = el.simpleName.toString()
      val pack = processingEnv.elementUtils.getPackageOf(el).toString()
      val filename = "Proxy$className"

      val classBuilder = TypeSpec.classBuilder(filename)
      val primaryConstructorBuilder = FunSpec.constructorBuilder()
      val secondaryConstructorBuilder = FunSpec.constructorBuilder().addParameter("json", JsonObject::class)
      val secondaryConstructorCodeBlocks = mutableListOf<CodeBlock>()
      el.enclosedElements.forEach {
        if (it.kind == ElementKind.FIELD) {
          val name = it.simpleName.toString()
          val kClass = getClass(it)              // get the corresponding Kotlin class
          val jsonTypeName = getJsonTypeName(it) // get the corresponding type name in methods of JsonObject

          classBuilder.addProperty(PropertySpec.builder(name, kClass).initializer(name).build())
          primaryConstructorBuilder.addParameter(name, kClass)
          secondaryConstructorCodeBlocks.add(CodeBlock.of("json.get$jsonTypeName(\"$name\")"))
        }
      }
      secondaryConstructorBuilder.callThisConstructor(secondaryConstructorCodeBlocks)
      classBuilder
        .addAnnotation(DataObject::class)
        .addModifiers(KModifier.DATA)
        .primaryConstructor(primaryConstructorBuilder.build())
        .addFunction(secondaryConstructorBuilder.build())
        .addFunction(
          FunSpec.builder("toJson").returns(JsonObject::class).addStatement("return JsonObject.mapFrom(this)").build()
        )
      val generatedFile = FileSpec.builder(pack, filename).addType(classBuilder.build()).build()
      generatedFile.writeTo(processingEnv.filer)
    }
    return true
  }
```

Then I can get the correct generated file by simply writing the original `data class`, but when I execute the building after cleaning, I still get the following error:

```
Could not generate model for DatabaseService#createEntity(ProxyEntity,io.vertx.core.Handler<io.vertx.core.AsyncResult<java.lang.Void>>): type ProxyEntity is not legal for use for a parameter in proxy
```

It seems that the generated annotation `@DataObject` is not processed.

So what should I do? Is there a better solution?

Comment: Did you solve your issue?